# Images put to storage are saved as 'octet-stream' rather than image/jpeg (firebase and ReactNative)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-image-picker

I am using the camera(react-native-image-Picker) to take a pick and save it to storage.
Here is how I am doing it.

```
const saveImage = async () => {
    const id = firebase.firestore().collection('food').doc().id
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref()
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.fileName) //name of image to store
    await fileRef.put(file) //store image

    firebase.firestore().collection("food").doc(id).update({
      image: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        name: file.fileName,
        url: await fileRef.getDownloadURL()
      })
    })
}
```

```
console.log(typeof file);
gives => "object"

console.log(file);
//gives => 
file = {height: 2322, 
uri:"content://com.photodocumentation.imagepickerprovidlib_temp_7a0448df-1fac-4ac7-a47c-402c62ecce4c.jpg", 
width: 4128, 
fileName: "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_7a0448df-1fac-4ac7-a47c-402c62ecce4c.jpg", 
type: "image/jpeg"}
```

Results:
In Firebase (storage) The image is being saved as application/octet-stream instead of image/jpeg.
The image is not shown, it says undefined when downloaded from storage.

Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I was able to fix it:

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(file.uri)
    const blob = await response.blob();
    var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("FolderName");
    return ref.put(blob)
}
```

Comment: Do we need to close blob? As XMLHttpRequest blob.close() ?

Comment: No, you do not need to manually close a blob in XMLHttpRequest. A blob (binary large object) is a data type in JavaScript that represents a large binary object, such as an image or video file. When you create a blob, it is automatically managed by the JavaScript runtime and will be automatically cleaned up when it is no longer needed. @degergio

Answer (score 0):

The [`Reference#put()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) method accepts a `Blob`, `Uint8Array` or `ArrayBuffer`. Your "file" object doesn't appear to be any of these.

Instead, we need to read the file into memory (using `react-native-fs` - referred to as  RNFS) and then upload that data along with the required metadata. Because the file is read as base64 by RNFS, we will use [`Reference#putString`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#putstring) instead as it accepts Base64 strings for uploads.

```
const rnfs = require('react-native-fs');

const saveImage = async () => {
  const capture = /* this is your "file" object, renamed as it's not a `File` object */
  const fileRef = firebase.storage().ref(capture.fileName);
  const captureBase64Data = await rnfs.readFile(capture.uri, 'base64');
  const uploadSnapshot = await fileRef.putString(captureBase64Data, 'base64', {
    contentType: capture.type,
    customMetadata: {
      height: capture.height,
      width: capture.width
    }
  });

  // const id = colRef.doc().id and colRef.doc(id).update() can be replaced with just colRef.add() (colRef being a CollectionReference)

  return await firebase.firestore().collection('food').add({
    image: {
      name: capture.fileName,
      url: await fileRef.getDownloadURL()
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This is the error that I am getting:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fs

I tried to do this: 
fs const fs = require('fs');
But still it is not working

Comment: @Byusa Sorry that was a typo on my part, it should be `rnfs` not `fs`

Comment: Still, it does not work. It does not show any error and it doesn't save anything to the storage.

Comment: So `saveImage().catch(e => console.error(e))` does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution: Image reference in uploadBytesResumable() method

```js
const storageRef = ref(storage,`product-images/${image.name}`);
uploadBytesResumable(storageRef,image);
```